# "[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-btn" Jest + Vue 3 + Vuetify 3 + Vite + Testing-library/vue

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuetify.js

It is not possible to render the component in which the v-btn from vuetify is located.

AppButton.test.js

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/vue";
import AppButton from "./AppButton.vue";

test("render AppButton", () => {
    render(AppButton);

    screen.debug();
});
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: "jsdom",
    moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "json", "vue"],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
        "^.+\\.vue$": "@vue/vue3-jest",
    },
    testEnvironmentOptions: {
        customExportConditions: ["node", "node-addons"],
    },
};
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }]],
};
```

When testing starts, a warning appears:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-btn
    If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
      at <AppButton ref="VTU_COMPONENT" > 
      at <VTUROOT>
```

Does anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because Vuetify needs to be installed with `app.use` on your Vue instance, while your test run in different environment and know nothing about what happens in your `main.js` file.
You can fix it by having a custom render function that would load all important modules (if more appear in the future):

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/vue";

import { vuetify } from "./src/vuetify/vuetify";
const customRender = (component, options) => {
  return render(component, { ...options, global: { plugins: [vuetify] } });
};

export { customRender as render };
```

vuetify.js:

```
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
import * as components from "vuetify/components";
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";
import "vuetify/styles";

export const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
});
```

and use the same vuetify in `app.js`:

```
import { vuetify } from "./vuetify/vuetify";


const app = createApp(App);

app.use(vuetify);
```

Comment: done everything you recommended, but now shows it
 "Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.
By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers."

Comment: @dshinkarenko can you provide your jest.config.js and babel.config.js files?

Comment: added to the description